# Where is the actual location of items stored using HttpContext.Response.Cache?

Tags: httpcontext.cache

I'm using HttpContext.Response.Cache to cache the responses from some of my HttpHandlers. My question should be simple but so far looking on Google I've not found a definite answer.

I would like to know where the cached items are stored when using HttpContext.Response.Cache? Please note I'm not looking for information on how to use it, there's lots of info on Google and MSDN for that.

I think that HttpContext.Response.Cache stores items in memory but could it also be storing things in an actual file, say for example on the C: drive?